# Java Collectors: Grouping a list of Object into a list of other objects with calculated values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I've been recently getting my hands on Java 8 and its Stream API, and recently its Collectors API, and I see it has the potential to do many many transformations to stream, but I have one situation where I'm not sure if possible with java 8 or even possible at all. I have two classes:

```
public class ClassA{
    public int group
    public int id
    public String title
    public String description
    public String keyword
    public String specialValue
}

public class ClassB{
    public String newTitle
    public String joinedDescriptions
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to generate from a List of ClassA objects, a grouped list of ClassB objects with values calculated from ClassA's fields. Concretely:

- Grouping ClassA by a combination of group and id
- The grouped ClassB instance will have a newTitle = title when keyword = 1, or newTitle = specialValue when keyword = 2
- And finally joinedDescriptions, is concatenation of all descriptions from the grouped ClassA instances.

I know that it is possible using Collectors' groupingBy to group ClassA instances using a lambda of the sort classA -> String.valueOf(classA.group) + String.valueOf(classA.id), or similar, but I don't know to achieve the other calculated values for each grouped instance.

I hope it is explained well enough.

Comment: What would be the expected output? `Map<Integer,Map<Integer,ClassB>>`? And according to which instance of ClassA will you determine the `newTitle` of the corresponding `ClassB` (since there can be multiple instances in the same group)?

Comment: Add a constructor in B that takes a list of A and implement your rules in that constructor

Comment: I've reworded and expanded the question to include more concrete details on the rules, should be even clearer and more precise now.

Comment: Hi Kev, I've rolled back the edits you made as you've completely changed the context of this post. please consider asking a new question **with an attempt** and I along with others onsite will be willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below are the steps to take; similar to what @Joakim Danielson mentioned in the comments:

group the source list as you've mentioned in your post and then add a constructor in `ClassB` that takes a list of `ClassA` and then performs the logic you've mentioned in terms of setting the title and joining the descriptions:

so this would be your stream pipeline:

```
List<ClassB> result = source.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(s -> s.getGroup() + "" + s.getId())) // Map<String, List<ClassA>>
                .values()  // Collection<List<ClassA>>
                .stream() // Stream<List<ClassA>>
                .map(ClassB::new) // Stream<ClassB>
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); //List<ClassB>>
```

and you'll need a constructor in ClassB defined as:

```
public ClassB(List<ClassA> source) {
        ClassA item = source.get(0);
        if(“1”.equals(item.getKeyword())
             this.newtitle = item.getTitle();
        else if(“2”.equals(item.getKeyword())
             this.newtitle = “specialValue”; // or make a call to a method to compute the value
        this.joinedDescriptions = String.join(“, “, source.stream().map(ClassA::getDescription).collect(toList()));
}
```

Comment: I've expanded the question with more details, in case the answer can be adapted to keep those in mind.
But in any case, that gives me some good directions for it to work for now, so thanks a lot.

Comment: @KevS 1) avoid changing the requirements of the post completely after someone has answered as it makes the answer no longer as valid. I am going to roll back the post. 2) this edit of yours deserves a completely new question and don't forget to post your attempt before posting otherwise the audience won't take it well if you just list requirements but didn't show any effort. 3) I've done enough in terms of coding for your initial post so I'll let ask a new question as mentioned **with an attempt** or you can take the current solution and play around with it to fit your needs.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.
Sorry for the newbie mistake.

Comment: It’s strongly discouraged to use string concatenation of objects for key generation. That’s error prone, *especially* as in this specific case, both are `int` numbers so concatenating, e.g. `123` with `45` and `12` with `345`, is just a bug waiting to happen. Just use `groupingBy(s -> Arrays.asList(s.getGroup(), s.getId()))` to get keys without ambiguity and even be more efficient, as it avoids the expensive string operations.

Comment: @Holger good shout!, That didn't come to my mind until you've mentioned it. I'll keep that in mind for future solutions. thanks.